# Zend How to update table value using own table field value

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

How to do this on Zend DB Table? Like,

```
UPDATE location AS main
  SET main.parent_location = 28, 
  main.description = CONCAT(
          (SELECT sub.description FROM wms_location AS sub WHERE sub.id_location=28), 
           main.designation
      ) 
WHERE main.id_location in (11, 14);
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->update(
    "parent_location" => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        "CONCAT(" . (string)$subSelect . ", designation)"
    ),
    "id_location IN(11, 14)"
);
```

I'm not sure about the aliases - whether they're possible and whether they're needed.